# glm () function Error: inner loop 1; cannot correct step size In addition: Warning message: step size truncated due to divergence

Tags: r, glm

I would appreciate any help with my GLM. I have been working on this code for a couple days now and don't understand whats happening. I keep getting error messages when I try to run the Anova such as:
"Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found: please supply starting values
In addition: Warning message:
In log(ifelse(y == 0, 1, y/mu)) : NaNs produced"

Here is a reproducible ex with a subset of my data:

libraries:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyselect)
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)
library(car)
library(ggplot2)
library(DHARMa)
library(car)
```

Data (subset):

```
# dput(test_belowground_roots)
structure(list(Species = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L), .Label = c("Distichlis", 
"Extriplex", "Frankenia", "Jaumea", "Salicornia", "Spergularia"
), class = "factor"), Elevation = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("High", 
"Low"), class = "factor"), Percent_Cow = c(0.0119370443654553, 
1.66023021380997, 0.0542749222973947, 0.0119270741698501, 0.0522473975753483, 
0.157215899671179, 0.0445436806597244, 0.101171207378294, 0.20464563691533, 
0.200685552140693, 0.0955257147599705, 0.139873571360959, 0.169129706492988, 
0.0631593917819073, 0.0220579401671932, 0.0510378219287149, 1.75877939665832, 
2.09257235618206, 0.0790842872888485, 0.461929074484505, 0.465830794247236, 
0.333824456962495, 0.151239791714465, 1.18860834090543, 0.0952218886225137, 
0.0861387423449267, 0.134870257139608, 0.0223709567815311, 0.167903482108886, 
0.863208719386142, 0.213773300639105, 0.0684185944614081, 0.0390698497360118, 
0.125854070731044, 0.229835409638795, 0.23344705776396, 0.0429188489053832, 
0.0329161246438321, 0.0704045005869568, 0.0298620745384123, 0.151748969386003, 
0.0134345440878063, 0.0635753600210511, 0.0420866348707646, 0.0338608286092187, 
0.109888274570288, 0.0524091943658822)), row.names = c(NA, -47L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

code for glm:

```
test_belowground_roots$Species<-as.factor(test_belowground_roots$Species)
test_belowground_roots$Elevation<-as.factor(test_belowground_roots$Elevation)

test_belowground_roots$Percent_Cow <- as.numeric(test_belowground_roots$Percent_Cow)

options("contrasts")

options(contrasts=c("contr.sum","contr.poly"))

options("contrasts")

hist(test_belowground_roots$Percent_Cow, breaks=15)

shapiro.test(test_belowground_roots$Percent_Cow)

qqp(test_belowground_roots$Percent_Cow, "norm")

model<-glm(Percent_Cow~Elevation*Species,family=Gamma(link="inverse"),data=test_belowground_roots)

summary(model)

Anova(model, type=3)
```

Comment: Just a guess: This might be telling you that using type=3 prevents a reasoned application of analysis of variance. You should read the help page for `?Anova` and then explain why you are choosing that option when it is ridiculed by most of R Core. If you have cogent reasons for using type =3 then you may need to take your question and your detailed explanations over to stats.stackexchange.com and try to convince real statisticians that this should make sense.

Comment: To add to @IRTFM’s comment: type 3 analyses don’t make sense when the model includes interactions.

Comment: If you are not sure how to pick the appropriate type of ANOVA, see [How to interpret type I, type II, and type III ANOVA and MANOVA?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/20452/how-to-interpret-type-i-type-ii-and-type-iii-anova-and-manova).

Comment: I think Limey might be more correct than my broad critique of Type III models. It  turns out that non-interaction models will still allow `Anova` to produce a result with tpe=3 but will give you the same output as with tyep=2.

Comment: "In general, if there is no significant interaction effect, then type II is more powerful, and follows the principle of marginality. If interaction is present, then type II is inappropriate while type III can still be used, but results need to be interpreted with caution" Thank you for your responses, I have now posted it on stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: I added one to my y variable and now its working.. is this legitimate since I added one to all values?